# Any way to ignore `Missing file doc comment` Yii2 using PHp Strom?

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

How i can remove the error so i don't have to add file tag before namespace and class tag for after name space

```
namespace backend\controllers;

use common\models\helpers\Frontend\DropdownHelper;
use common\models\Lookup;
use common\models\Partner;
use common\models\PartnerSearch;
use Yii;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\web\Response;
```

Missing file tags and class tags error in phpStorm.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: please add the actual code , you are old enough on this community to know the rules that you dont provide images for the code

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i want to add the Yii2 standard now

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Please see the link https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-coding-standards/issues/23

Comment: you have changed the whole question that i answered , you cant do that , you should post a separate question and mark the answer if it works ]

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Sorry bro i will do it and creat another question please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some parts of your code may be unable to conform to your coding standard. You can ignore file parts in the following way

```
$xmlPackage = new XMLPackage;
// phpcs:disable
$xmlPackage['error_code'] = get_default_error_code_value();
$xmlPackage->send();
// phpcs:enable
```

In your case you are trying to ignore the doc block for the page and the class, so you should start the `// phpcs:disable` before the `namespace` and then close it using `// phpcs:enable` right after the opening braces of the class `{`.

I am adding the sample code to ignore the docs block for the file and class below using my own code as you never added the actual code but the image

```
<?php
// phpcs:disable
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
use yii\web\Response;

/**
 * ApiKeysController implements the CRUD actions for ApiKeys model.
 */
class ApiKeysController extends Controller
{
    // phpcs:enable

}
```

---

**Note: Before `PHP_CodeSniffer version 3.2.0`, use `// @codingStandardsIgnoreStart`
instead of `// phpcs:disable`, and use `// @codingStandardsIgnoreEnd` instead of 
`// phpcs:enable`. The `@codingStandards` syntax is deprecated and will be removed in 
`PHP_CodeSniffer version 4.0`.**

Comment: @MuhmmadQasimAslam Yes helpfull to hide the errors,